# How to re-render meteor blaze template when local array changes?

Tags: arrays, templates, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

Having worked a lot with AngularJS over the past 2+ years and starting to get into MeteorJS 1.2 at the moment there are some aspects of the blaze templating layer that feel quite unintuitive to me but probably have an easy solution.

I want to have a "Create poll" form which has the following fields:

- question, text field
- poll option, text field
- add option, button
- list of options, repeater of `<li>`s based on a local `options` array
- list items have a remove button

In essence I want to be able to populate the poll option field, click "add option" and have this option render in the list repeater below the poll option text field in a readonly fashion (plain text).

My issue currently is that without using something like ReactiveArray the blaze template does not rerender when I push items in the local array variable `options`.

What is the correct way of going about this?

**Code below:**

`poll.create.html` template:

```
<template name="pollCreate">
    <form class="form form--create">
        <section class="form__section">
            <!-- Question Field -->
            <input class="form__field" type="text" name="question" required>

            <!-- Poll Options -->
            <ul class="form__list">

                <!-- Poll option form field -->
                <li class="form__list-item form__list-item--creator">
                    <input class="form__field" type="text" name="pollOption">
                    <button class="form__button--add" type="button">&plus;</button>
                </li>

                <!-- Render the options added above -->
                {{#each option in optionList}}
                <li class="form__list-item--option" data-index="{{option.index}}">
                    <span class="form__list-item-value">{{option.label}}</span>
                    <button type="button" class="form__button--delete">&times;</button>
                </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </section>

        <button class="form__button--submit" type="submit">Create Poll</button>
        <button class="form__button--reset" type="reset">Clear Fields</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

`poll.create.client.js` (`Polls = new Mongo.Collection("polls")` is in a server file)

```
// Setup
Template.pollCreate.onCreated(function () {

    // Local poll variable to capture the options in.
    this.options = [
        { index: 0, label: 'BurgerBurger' },
        { index: 1, label: 'BetterBurger' }
    ];

});

// Events
Template.pollCreate.events({
    /**
     * Adds an option to the local array for saving as part of the submit in the Posts.insert call.
     * @param event
     * @param instance
     */
    'click .form__button--add': function ( event, instance ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get current option element
        var option = instance.find('[name="pollOption"]');

        // Store in a local array
        instance.options.push({
            index: instance.options.length,
            label: option.value
        });

        // Clear field so it's ready for another option
        option.value = '';
    },
    /**
     * Delete an existing option.
     * @param event
     * @param instance Template.instance
     */
    'click .form__button--delete': function ( event, instance ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var listItemElement = event.target.parentNode;
        var itemIndex = instance.$(listItemElement).data('index');

        // Delete option from reactive source array
        instance.options.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    },
    /**
     * Submit the Poll Create form which will run Polls.insert with the question and options
     * @param event
     * @param instance
     */
    'submit .form--create': function ( event, instance ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var question = instance.find('[name="question"]');
        var options = instance.options;

        var poll = {
            question: question.value,
            options: options
        };

        Polls.insert(poll);
    }
});

// Helpers
Template.pollCreate.helpers({
    optionList: function () {
        const instance = Template.instance();
        return instance.options;
    }
});
```

I can see the `instance.options` array values changing as I push or splice options in and out of it but it doesn't seem to re-render the template and the list of options never changes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want the ui to reactively update you need to have two things, (1) a reactive data source and (2) a reactive context.

Right now you've got the reactive context - that's the Template helper `optionList` which will re-render any time a reactive data source referenced by it changes. The problem is the option list is not a reactive data source, it's just a vanilla array. So when the `Templace.instance().options` array changes, the helper does not know to rerender it.

The fix is very easy - just make `Template.instance.options` a reactive data source by using one of Meteor's built in reactive structures `ReactiveVar` or `ReactiveDict` or by using `MiniMongo`. `ReactiveArray` which you mentioned would work too - I believe that's community maintained and not a core package, but it's the same idea.

The quickest and easiest solution here is to save the whole array to one `ReactiveVar`:

```
Template.pollCreate.onCreated(function(){
  this.options = new ReactiveVar([
    { index: 0, label: 'BurgerBurger' },
    { index: 1, label: 'BetterBurger' }
  ]);
});

Template.pollCreate.helpers({
  optionList({
    return Template.instance().options.get();
  })
});
```

That ought to do it.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for that. Just tried it out and works nicely. The only question now is (I could be missing something) but I cannot interact with the `ReactiveVar` like a native array right? I.e. calling `array.push` and `array.splice` on it directly. So is the only way to change the content by first calling the `ReactiveVar.get()` method and then modifying the result and then re-setting the ReactiveVar via `ReactiveVar.set(new)`?

Comment: Thats right. And probably why the package creator built ReactiveArray

Comment: Thanks again, I've just played around with this scenario but using MiniMongo to create a local `Options` collection and then using `insert`, `remove` and ultimately `.find().fetch()` to save options as part of a poll and that feels better to me from code pattern point of view. Is there any downsides to using these client only mongo collections for this use case?

Comment: Not that I can think of. One nice thing about ReactiveVar/ReactiveDict is that you can easily keep their state internal to a template instance - which can be a plus or a minus.